# .NET Core / Kestrel Application is shutting down without reason

Tags: iis, .net-core, iis-7.5, kestrel-http-server, .net-core-2.2

An existing setup where .net core (2.2) apis are hosted under IIS 7.5 ran smooth and nice so far.

Suddenly I experienced that the logs hold the message `Application is shutting down...` without any indicators of errors or other reasons. I started recognizing this when there suddenly were a lot more log files generated than before.

I a not sure but that could have started when I moved from .NET Core 2.1 to 2.2.

Does anyone know if this is a feature or a bug, harmfull or intended?

Comment: Check IIS application pool recycle events/shutdown events, and then compare the timestamps with the ones you get in ASP.NET Core logs.

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you found any solution to that?

Comment: unfortunatly not yet. I assume this could be somehow related to "the new" in process hosting but haven't been able to dig into it deep enough

Comment: Did u ever figure this out my host swears they support .net 5

Answer (score 1):

I was getting exactly the same message on my development environment. Even `dotnet run` wouldn't work.  Editing the `~/Properties/launchSettings.json` file and selecting a higher port fixed it.  (I switched from port 1306 to port 30931).
I still haven't been able to figure out what is suddenly blocking port 1306.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue building a .Net Core 3.1 Worker Service. The issue for me was that my Execute method wasn't actually using the await operator.

I fixed the issue by changing a line of logging to this:

```
 await Task.Run(() => _logger.LogInformation("Starting Service"));
```